# Issue One command and Run Multiple Ruby Files

Tags: ruby, scripting

I have to run a whole bunch of ruby scripts to generate some results. In which order does not matter. I just don't want to do Ruby file1.rb, Ruby file2.rb, Ruby file3.rb...one by one.

Could I write a script that group all files together and issue command only once to run them all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do it ruby-style and use `rake` gem.

I would create file named "rakefile.rb" and this would be its content:

```
task :default do
    FileList['file*.rb'].each { |file| ruby file }
end
```

Then I would call `rake` in my favourite shell and I would enjoy it.

Bonus: It's **multiplatform**.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using bash and all the ruby files you want to run are in the current directory you could do:

```
for file in `ls ./*.rb`; do
  ruby $file
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Have `runall.rb` contain:

```
(1..3).each do |i|
  `ruby file#{i}.rb`
end
```

and call `ruby runall.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a sh script called startruby.sh that looks like this (this example doesn't work):

```
ruby ruby1.rb;
ruby ruby2.rb;
etc.
```

And then run

```
sh startruby.sh
```

And it will lauch all the ruby script after each other.
Offcourse you can also make it more advanced with a for loop and such, but this is the easiest/quickest way.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want, but if you want all the files loaded together, maybe something like ...

```
ruby -I. -e "ARGV.each {|f| load f}" file*.rb
```